# How to parse values from JSON. I am trying to list individual values like a dictionary in python

Tags: json, go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/AutoScalingMultiAZWithNotifications.template")

    if err !=nil {
        fmt.Println(err)

    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    v := make(map[string] interface{})

    json.Unmarshal(body, &v)

    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Comment: The program decodes the json to a map. Maps are somewhat like a dictionary in Python. Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: There is a field, parameters in that list which I can parse. However within that , there is another field called VpcId. How do I get it. It tells me (type interface {} does not support indexing)

Comment: Unmarshal returns an error if something goes wrong, you are ignoring the error. Try this: `err = json.Unmarshal(body, &v)` and then `if err != nil {fmt.Println(err)}`

Comment: Decode the JSON to Go struct types that match the structure of the JSON document.  Use struct field selector expressions to get the value for of interest.

Comment: For aws cloudformation you can use [github.com/awslabs/goformation](https://github.com/awslabs/goformation)

Comment: Thanks , However is the only way using a struct field.

Comment: You can use type assertions to pick out the value you want. It’s simpler to define the types.  You only need to declare the fields you are interested in. There are third party tools that generate Go types given an example JSON document.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/AutoScalingMultiAZWithNotifications.template")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    v := make(map[string]interface{})
    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&v); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // index into map v and type-assert the value
    if Parameters, ok := v["Parameters"].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
        // index into Parameters and if found, print
        if VpcId, ok := Parameters["VpcId"]; ok {
            fmt.Println(VpcId)
        }
    }

}
```